# PySpark dataframe write to orc not allowing column names with hyphen

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, illegalargumentexception, orc

I am new to PySpark. I have a csv file with hyphen in column names. I could successfully read the file into a dataframe. However while writing the df to orc file I get an error like below-

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing required char ':' at
'struct

When I renamed the columns by removing hyphen, I could write the dataframe to orc. But I need the column names to have hyphen because I want to append this orc to an existing orc which has hyphen in column names.

Could someone please help me with this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use backtick " ` " to enclose the column name.

Like: `column-name`

read the data in a dataframe and create a new empty dataframe with the desired structure

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
result= spark.read.orc(path)
schema = StructType([
  StructField('col-name', StringType(), True),
  StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
  StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.emptyRDD(),schema)

df.unionAll(result).show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But is it possible to specify column name in spark.write.format statement?